# Are there any objects that do not contain the __name__ attribute?

Tags: python, object

Are there any objects that do not contain the `__name__` attribute? Does the object data always comprise the object name?

Comment: *most* objects lack that attribute...

Comment: In python almost everything is an object. Most do not contain `__name__`. `int`, `str`, `float` ...

Comment: `object()` or `42` or `'foo'` or `[]` or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any objects that do not contain the `__name__` attribute?

Of course:

```
>>> (4).__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> (3.14).__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> (6+8j).__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> 'hello'.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> [].__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> ....__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

And on and on it goes...